# Why is my code not adding the value to the dropdown properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown list. In that list, I've got a bunch of items populated by the database.

When I make a selection, I want the new value of this dropdown list to be set to whatever the text is, in essence. To accomplish this, I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
            $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
            $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).text());
        });
    });
```

To test this, I inserted an alert:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
            $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
            $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).text());

            var tmp = $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val();
            alert("Current .btn val is: " + tmp);
        });
    });
```

At this point, the alert says:

> Current .btn val is: [desired value]

which is what I want.

However, when the following code runs, later on in a different script...

```
var tmp = $("#fixVersionDropdownButton").val();
var tmp1 = $("#fixVersionDropdown").val();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chartRefresh").click(function () {
        alert("Fix Version Dropdown Button value is: " + tmp);
        alert("Fix Version Dropdown value is: " + tmp1)
    });
});
```

the resulting alert simply says

> Fix Version Dropdown Button value is:

followed by

> Fix Version Dropdown value is:

The code for my dropdown is as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="margin:5px;">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" id="fixVersionDropdownButton" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Choose Fix Version
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="fixVersionDropdown"></ul>
    </div>
```

It appears to me as though I'm either not ACTUALLY setting the value somehow (though this seems unlikely based on the first alert... maybe I'm setting the value of something else somehow?) or I'm not reading the value correctly.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're attempting to read the values of the elements before they exist in the DOM. Move the `tmp` and `tmp1` declarations in to the document.ready handler, possibly even inside the `click` handler, depending on your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To rephrase what you're trying to do

When you click on `$('#chartRefresh')`, you want `$("#fixVersionDropdownButton").val()` and `$("#fixVersionDropdown").val()` **at the moment of the click**.

### Why your code doesn't do that

As @Rory McCrossan mentioned, the values of those elements do not exist in the DOM before they're read, because the elements themselves don't exist. After the `tmp` and `tmp1` assignments, DOM is loaded. Some time passes, DOM finishes loading, then the `callback` `$(document).ready(callback)` is called. At this point, `tmp` and `tmp1` still have "no values". When the click handler is called, `tmp` and `tmp1` still have "no values", explaining your result.

### One way to make your code do what you want it to do

You must "**catch**" the following instants in time:

**DOM is finished loading.** Why? You need to guarantee that all the elements (e.g. `$('#chartRefresh')`, `$("#fixVersionDropdownButton")`, and `$("#fixVersionDropdown")`) in the DOM exist before attaching event handlers to them or getting their values in this case.

**Click on `$('#chartRefresh')`** Why? You need to guarantee that the values you want to read into `tmp` and `tmp1` are the values at the instant the click is performed.

To "**catch**" these instants and guarantee the right code occurs at these instants, review the following **callbacks**.

Callback that runs when DOM is finished loading: `callback` in `$(document).ready(callback)`

Callback that runs when `$('#chartRefresh')` is clicked: "`callback` in `$('#chartRefresh').click(callback)`

### One way to code this up

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chartRefresh").click(function () {
        var tmp = $("#fixVersionDropdownButton").val();
        var tmp1 = $("#fixVersionDropdown").val();
        alert("Fix Version Dropdown Button value is: " + tmp);
        alert("Fix Version Dropdown value is: " + tmp1)
    });
});
```

### References

https://api.jquery.com/click/

Side note: for more advanced event delegation, which addresses not only existing elements but future elements http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This worked. I swear the "DOM isn't ready yet" issue gets me 90% of the time. I appreciate the help.